# Entity Framework : query vs foreach

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

If it okay to use `foreach` for a simple query like this? Or should I always use the query thing ?

```
    public static Staff GetTeacher(Context context, int staffId)
    {
        foreach (Staff staff in context.Staff)
        {
            if(staff.StaffID == staffId)
            {
                return staff;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static object GetTeacher(Context context, int staffId)
    {
        var staff = from teacher in context.Staff
                    where teacher.StaffID == staffId
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = teacher.StaffID,
                        Teacher = teacher.FirstName + " " + teacher.LastName
                    };
        return staff;              
    }
```

Comment: The foreach will loop over your entire database table but the query will construct a SQL query that only pulls out the relevant record(s).

Comment: Another option if StaffID is a primary key is to use [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find?view=efcore-6.0) method, see the docs and there is also [FindAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.findasync?view=efcore-6.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` will loop over every record in your database table until it finds a match, meaning it might eventually pull every single record into memory. That could be incredibly slow.

The Linq query will construct an SQL statement that only pulls out the relevant record(s).

So the second option is far better. However, it looks like you tried to fix the fact your second query give an enumerable list of staff object by making the function return an object. Instead, you can make the entire thing look much nicer, something like this:

```
public static Staff GetTeacher(Context context, int staffId)
{
    return context.Staff.Single(s => s.StaffID == staffId);
}
```

This will be the most efficient method. It will throw an exception if there is no matching `staffId` in the database. That might be a good thing for you. If not, change it to use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Single`.

Side note: I'm concerned about the method being `static`. This suggests the DbContext might be shared or long-lived which are both bad things.

Comment: I would suggest not use `Single` but `First` instead. It may lead to full table scan. Yes many databases have enough clever query plan optimizer, but it may happen that `SELECT TOP 2 … ` will continue looking for non existing record in whole table.

Comment: @DavidG How is that approach with the .Single method called ? I would like to learn more about it.

About the methods being static - I use them like this: Is it okay or should I use different approach ?
`
private void AddStudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context context = new Context();

    Student student = new Student(.......);
    StudentRepository.AddStudent(context, student);

    context = null;
 }
`